# Created a custom msg to support an array of strings but I get thhis warning msg when i use it

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a custom msg which is an array or strings. this is my declaration:

```
    string[] data
```

However when I use this msg, i get a warning. I dont  understand why I get this warning.

```
   [WARN] [WallTime: 1401683261.952534] Could not process inbound connection: topic types do not match:[std_msgs/String] vs. [beginner_tutorials/StringArray]{'message_definition': 'string data\n\n', 'callerid': '/rostopic_3711_1401673205336', 'tcp_nodelay': '0', 'md5sum': '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1', 'topic': '/tag_history', 'type': 'std_msgs/String'}
```

Can somebody please tell me how I can get rid of this? THanks

My code where i am using ths StringArray datatype:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from beginner_tutorials.msg import StringArray


def callback(data):
    global c
    str=StringArray()
    pub = rospy.Publisher('tag_history',StringArray)
    c.append(data.data)
    if len(c)>3:
       c=c[1:4]    
    str.data=c
    print str
   pub.publish(str)


 def listener():
 
 rospy.init_node('tag_history', anonymous=True)
 
 rospy.Subscriber("DA_tags", String, callback)
 rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
 
 global c
 c=[]
 listener()
```

This is the data i see when i enter "rostopic echo DA_tags"

```
 uahmed9@uahmed9-Lenovo-IdeaPad-U410-Touch:~$ rostopic echo DA_tags
 data: Query-yn
 ---
 data: Unknown
 ---
 data: Unknown
 ---
 data: Acknowledge
 ---
 data: Unknown
 ---
 data: Unknown
 ---
```

This is the output for rostopic info DA_tags

```
uahmed9@uahmed9-Lenovo-IdeaPad-U410-Touch:~$ rostopic info DA_tags
Type: std_msgs/String

Publishers: 
 * /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener (http://127.0.0.1:59178/)

Subscribers: 
 * /tag_history_32168_1401828816089 (http://uahmed9-Lenovo-IdeaPad-U410-Touch:51087/)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172509/created-a-custom-msg-to-support-an-array-of-strings-but-i-get-thhis-warning-msg-when-i-use-it../) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-06-02**:
Seems like you're publishing to a topic of Type 'beginner_tutorials/StringArray'. Is this correct? If this is the case you have to use this type.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-02**:
yes I am publishing to that topic. I edited my post to paste my code for reference.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-06-02**:
Please post also the output of rostopic info /DA_tags. BTW: Why do you mention your custom message? I'm asking because you don't use it.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-02**:
the data on DA_tags consists of words like "check","acknowledge","unknown" etc. Thse are the outputs from the classifier that I am impelemnting in ROS. Also I am using my custom message. I created StringArray following the message creation tutorial in the ROS documentation.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-06-03**:
Please post also the output of rostopic info /DA_tags.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-03**:
I edited the question to post the output. Take a look.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-06-03**:
Also I ran both the nodes today and I dont see the warning anymore. wonder what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, this message means that the subscriber on a topic was expecting one data type, but the publisher is using a different data type.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NagaDinesh1194](https://answers.ros.org/users/40046/nagadinesh1194/) on 2019-03-18**:
Exactly. Bu right now my requirement is that , i convert the message to the one that the topic is expecting.
Is that possible if so how?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-18**:
@NagaDinesh1194 it sounds like you have a different question. Please ask it as a new question instead of commenting on an old question.